# Week date range

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table objects, which stores data on real estate objects. Me need to use a query to calculate a new field that will display the date range from Monday to Sunday, which includes the date the object was created (for example, “2020-11-16 - 2020-11-22”)

```
create table objects(
   object_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
city_id int not null ,
price int ,
area_total int ,
status varchar(50) ,
class varchar(50) ,
action varchar(50) ,
date_create timestamp,
FOREIGN KEY(city_id) references avg_price_square_city(city_id)
);
```

Data in the table:

```
INSERT INTO objects (object_id, city_id, price, area_total, status, class, action, date_create) 
   VALUES (1, 1, 4600000, 72, 'active', 'Secondary', 'Sale', '2022-05-12 21:49:34');
INSERT INTO objects (object_id, city_id, price, area_total, status, class, action, date_create) 
   VALUES (2, 2, 5400000, 84, 'active', 'Secondary', 'Sale', '2022-05-19 21:49:35');
```

The query should display two fields: the object number and a range that includes the date it was created. How can this be done ?
P.S
I wrote this query,but he swears at the "-" sign:

```
SET @WeekRangeStart  ='2022/05/10';
SET @WeekRangeEnd  = '2022/05/17';
select object_id,@range := @WeekRangeStart '-' @WeekRangeEnd
FROM objects where @range = @WeekRangeStart and date_create between @WeekRangeStart and @WeekRangeEnd
UNION
select object_id,@range from objects where @`range` = @WeekRangeEnd;
```

Error:[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@WeekRangeEnd FROM objects where @range = @WeekRangeStart and date_create betwee' at line 1

I want to receive in query:

```
object_id  @range
1          2022/05/10 - 2022/05/17
```

The column @range must contain the date from the "date_create"

Comment: "but he swears at the "-" sign"   Please add the full error message that MySQL provides.  (But you cannot concatenate strings like this, you should use: `CONCAT(@WeekRangeStart, '-', @WeekRangeEnd)` )

Comment: Note: your SQL logic is completely incorrect....   Can you add expected output of this query ?

Comment: I corrected the mistakes on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @WeekRangeStart  = CAST('2022/05/10' as DATE);
SET @WeekRangeEnd  = CAST('2022/05/17' as DATE);
SET @range = CONCAT(@WeekRangeStart,' - ',@WeekRangeEnd) ;
-- select @range;
select 
   object_id,
   @range
FROM objects 
where DATE(date_create) between @WeekRangeStart and @WeekRangeEnd
UNION
select object_id,@range from objects 
;
```

Gives next result:

| object_id | @range |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-10 - 2022-05-17 |
| 2 | 2022-05-10 - 2022-05-17 |

- This result is the output of the SQL part that is put after the UNION. Because date_create is not between your WeekRangeStart and WeekRangeEnd.
  **You should take some time, and read the [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) documentation.**
- The variable `@range` is calculated before the SQL statement, because the value is a constant.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a51f185ed26851af7e5d07dd9677e74)

NOTE: You should try to use the same dateformat everywhere, and not mix date like `'2022-05-19 21:49:35'` and `2022/05/10`. Use `-` OR use `/`, but do not mix them...

EDIT: After the calirification "Me need to use a query to calculate a new field that will display the date range from Monday to Sunday,...":

You probably wanted to do:

```
SET @WeekDate = CAST('2022/05/10' as DATETIME);

SELECT 
   ADDDATE(@WeekDate, -(DAYOFWEEK(@WeekDate)-1) +1) as Monday,
   DATE_ADD(ADDDATE(@WeekDate, -(DAYOFWEEK(@WeekDate)-1) +9), INTERVAL -1 SECOND) as Sunday;
```

output:

| Monday | Sunday |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-09 00:00:00 | 2022-05-16 23:59:59 |

Comment: `SET @WeekRangeStart  = CAST('2022/01/10 00:23:00' as DATETIME);
SET @WeekRangeEnd  = CAST('2022/01/14 23:23:00' as DATETIME);
select
   object_id,
   @range := CONCAT(@WeekRangeStart,' - ',@WeekRangeEnd)
FROM objects
where date(date_create) between @WeekRangeStart and @WeekRangeEnd
;`                                                                                                                                                   I corrected your request and now it displays what I need."UNION
select object_id,@range from objects " Displays the original values without conditions

Comment: The values for `date_create` where changed since I copied the data which is used in the DBFIDDLE.... 

Comment: Your query is still unclear (because of your use of UNION)  When you only do `select object_id,@range from objects` you will get the same results (provided `@range` has the correct value)

Comment: Me need to use a query to calculate a new field that will display the date range from Monday to Sunday, which includes the date the object was created.Is it possible to do this in MySQL?

Comment: 51 minutes ago I commented (on your question): "Can you add expected output of this query ?" Now you are changing the question without providing this info ? 